# Can you explain the magic of these shiny app example?

Tags: html, r, web, github, shiny

Here is the famous [example](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example) of shinyapp on Rstudio main page.

`ui.R` define two tabPanels in the webpage.The first tab renders a map, and the second tab if for selecting date from a full datetable according to the `selectInput`.

part of the code:

```
 ...

 tabPanel("Data explorer",
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
        selectInput("states", "States", c("All states"="", structure(state.abb, names=state.name), "Washington, DC"="DC"), multiple=TRUE)
      ),
      column(3,
        conditionalPanel("input.states",
          selectInput("cities", "Cities", c("All cities"=""), multiple=TRUE)
        )
      ),
      column(3,
        conditionalPanel("input.states",
          selectInput("zipcodes", "Zipcodes", c("All zipcodes"=""), multiple=TRUE)
        )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(1,
        numericInput("minScore", "Min score", min=0, max=100, value=0)
      ),
      column(1,
        numericInput("maxScore", "Max score", min=0, max=100, value=100)
      )
    ),
    hr(),
    DT::dataTableOutput("ziptable")
  ),
...
```

1. I don't know which line of code define the variables, `state.name` and `state.abb`, which is used in 4th line of the block above.
2. The hierarchy select function is quite simple here. Why can it work without `choices` in the second and third `selectInput` function.

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/063-superzip-example/ui.R

Answer (score 0):

## 1

`state.abb` and `state.name` it s datasets which exists into R see `?state.abb`

## 2

There is also Server.r
with

```
observe({
    cities <- if (is.null(input$states)) character(0) else {
      filter(cleantable, State %in% input$states) %>%
        `$`('City') %>%
        unique() %>%
        sort()
    }
    stillSelected <- isolate(input$cities[input$cities %in% cities])
    updateSelectInput(session, "cities", choices = cities,
      selected = stillSelected)
  })
```

So choises changed dynamic from serever side